# Histogram plotting "AttributeError: max must be larger than min in range parameter."

Tags: python, histogram

I have a dataset (as a .txt file) used to make a histogram, but a journal has asked me to normalize the data and plot a histogram of the normalized data instead. However, I'm getting a "AttributeError: max must be larger than min in range parameter." error when I'm trying to plot the normalized data. Basically, H1 is my list of data (some may include nan values which I'm attempting to remove), and I'm trying to normalize the remaining data

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

H1 = np.loadtxt('histogramrate25p10area30.txt') #Import data from txt file

newH1 = [x for x in H1 if x != 'nan'] #Remove nan values
norm1 = [float(i)/max(newH1) for i in newH1] #Normalize remaining values

nbins1 = 400

plt.figure()

plt.subplot(111)
plt.hist(norm1, nbins1, color='purple', alpha=0.5)
plt.ylabel('Frequency', fontsize=20)

plt.show()
```

From browsing this website, the error resulted from the presence of nan values, but I thought in my newH1 list above, I've removed all the nan values, so I'm unsure what is causing this error.

Comment: I don't think you've successfully removed the NAN's. Try `newH1 = [x for x in H1 if x is not np.nan]` instead. I doubt that `plt.hist` plays nicely with the NAN's.

Comment: @Abdou Just tried it and I still get this "AttributeError: max must be larger than min in range parameter."

Comment: You must be carrying some `nans` between `newH1` and `norm1`. What is the shape of `H1`? Try printing `np.isnan(newH1).any()`  and `np.isnan(norm1).any()` to see if you still got `nans` in there.

Comment: @Abdou Just did both of those and they both say True (which I assume means I do have nans in there). The distribution of data is times, so everything is >0, but is heavily skewed right.

Comment: What do you get when print `H1.shape`? That determines the shape of the numpy array you loaded from the file.

Comment: @Abdou print H1.shape produces: (3000,)

Comment: Try the following: `newH1 = H1[~np.isnan(H1)]; norm1 = np.apply_along_axis(func1d=lambda x: x/ np.max(newH1),arr=newH1,axis=0); nbins1 = 400; plt.hist(norm1, nbins1, color='purple', alpha=0.5)`.

Comment: @Abdou Oh hey that seems to work!

Comment: Great! I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should do:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


H1 = np.loadtxt('histogramrate25p10area30.txt')

newH1 = H1[~np.isnan(H1)]
norm1 = np.apply_along_axis(func1d=lambda x: x/np.max(newH1), arr=newH1, axis=0)
nbins1 = 400
plt.hist(norm1, nbins1, color='purple', alpha=0.5)

plt.figure()

plt.subplot(111)
plt.hist(norm1, nbins1, color='purple', alpha=0.5)
plt.ylabel('Frequency', fontsize=20)

plt.show()
```

#### Explanation:

The script above loads the data with the help of the `np.loadtxt` function and subsequently removes the rows that contain null values. The latter is done by indexing the imported array with the boolean array `~np.isnan(H1)`. Here, `np.isnan` finds the rows where the values are `null` or `nan` and the `~` sign negates that; changing the `True` values to `False`, and vice-versa. Once that's done, it moves on to applying a function to each value of the new array. The function here is `lambda x: x/np.max(newH1)`; which basically divides each value of the array by the maximum value present in the new array.

The next step is to plot the histogram. We set the number of bins needed to 400 and use `plt.hist` to plot the histogram. There is also an added bonus to create a `figure` and then add a `subplot` to our `figure`. Subsequently, we use the `subplot` to draw the histogram.

I hope this proves useful.

Comment: Can you explain what you're doing here?

Comment: @spacetyper I've added some explanation.

Comment: Thank you for doing that

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue.
They are expecting a range of parameter.

```
plt.hist( DATAFRAME NAME, RANGE( min value, max value))
```

This solved the issue for me.